# Python Pandas:get str from series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I wanna get strings from Series that was drop duplicates.

Here is my sample code.

```
from pandas import DataFrame,Series

d = {'Sex' : Series(["Male","Male","Female","Female","Female","Male","Female","Female","Male"]),
      'Rank' : Series(["A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"]),
      'Num' : Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6]),
      'States' : Series(["Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio","Ohio"])}

df = DataFrame(d)
States = df.States.drop_duplicates()

print "This is "+States
```

I could get such strings that inclue Name: and dtype:

> 0    This is Ohio
>
> Name: States, dtype: object

I wanna only pick up "Ohio" from it.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Thanks! I can pickup States[0].

Answer (score 1):

```
States = df.drop_duplicates(['States'])
```

Then something like

```
print "This is " + States.States[0]
```

will give you the result you are looking for.